# JSONP and XMLHttpRequest question

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, jsonp

Am trying to understand the same origin policy in browsers (and also Javascript newbie) and ran into the JSONP page on wikipedia. The [How It Works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#How_it_works) section says -

> Now, consider that it is possible to specify any URL, including a URL that returns JSON, as the src > attribute for a  element. This means it is possible to retrieve JSON via a script element in > an HTML page.
>
> However, a JSON document is not a JavaScript program. If it is to be evaluated by the browser in a   element, the return value from the src URL must be executable JavaScript. In the JSONP usage pattern, the URL returns the dynamically-generated JSON, with a function call wrapped around it. This is the "padding" (or sometimes, "prefix") of JSONP.

My questions are -

- So is XMLHTTPRequest() supposed to return only javascript or html? Can it not return a pure json document?
- I thought the same origin policy does not apply to XMLHttpRequest() call. Why is there a need to inject a  tag into the DOM to make a call to a third party server? Is that how all the advertising add-ons to sites call home to collect data?
- At the end of it I did not understand JSONP at all. Can some one explain or refer me to a better explanation please?

Thanks,

- P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So is XMLHTTPRequest() supposed to return only javascript or html?

It can return any text you like (and maybe binary data, but I've never see that tried so I won't swear to it)

> Can it not return a pure json document?

It can.

> I thought the same origin policy does not apply to XMLHttpRequest() call.

The same origin policy most definitely **does** apply to XHR

> Why is there a need to inject a tag into the DOM to make a call to a third party server?

The same origin policy is bypassed by loading a script (with embedded data) from another origin.

This is because you aren't reading a remote resource using JavaScript. You are executing some remote JavaScript which comes with embedded data.

> At the end of it I did not understand JSONP at all. Can some one explain or refer me to a better explanation please?

JSON-P is just loading some JavaScript from another origin. That JavaScript consists of a single function call (to a function you define before adding the `<script>` element) with a single argument (a JS object or array literal).

Comment: Great answer.  I would add/clarify that what makes a JSONP script source special is it contains a callback function so it can call/affect your own scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also understand the reference to the XSS in the article now.